# Using CSS, how to rotate a 3D box 180 degrees on mouse enter and continue to 360 on leave?

Tags: html, css, 3d, transform

I have a little box, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hSnS/), that has to show its backside when the mouse enters, and should continue to 360 degrees ('back' to normal) when the mouse leaves again.

However, i don't want the animation to be aborted but instead continue to complete a 360 degree turn, even if the mouse enters and leaves quickly. Suppose the animation got to 30 degrees when the mouse leaves, it should continue to complete a 360 turn, passing the 180 (backside view).

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? I have trouble getting the animation to continue and in particular, to continue in the same direction of rotation, instead of reversing and going back to its starting position...

The javascript:

```
$('.cube').mouseenter(function(event){
  console.log(event);
  $(this).toggleClass('show-back',true);
});

$('.cube').mouseleave(function(event){
  console.log(event);
  $(this).toggleClass('show-back',false);
});
```

And CSS transform:

```
#cube.show-back {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY( -180deg );
     -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY( -180deg );
       -o-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY( -180deg );
          transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY( -180deg );
}
```

Clearly the code above, using a simple toggle, doesn't convey the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've peaked my curiosity, so I just had to see if it was possible :)

## Try this:

```
$(".cube").bind('transitionend', function() {
    // Reversing the animation flag for the mouse-leave
    if ($(this).data("animating")) {
        $(this).data("animating", false);
    } else {
        $(this).data("animating", true);
    }
});

$('.cube').mouseenter(function(event){
    $(this).data('animating', true);
    $(this).toggleClass('show-back',true);
});

$('.cube').mouseleave(function(event){
    $that = $(this);
    if ($that.data("animating")) {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            $that.toggleClass('show-back',false);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $that.toggleClass('show-back',false);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hSnS/2/)

The trick here was two fold:

1. First, you needed to make sure that you had a way of knowing if the animation was in progress or not (thus the sample binding above on transitionend).
2. Then you must know that this transition end will fire on the animation back as well, thus we toggled the animating flag.

Then a 1 second delay was added on the mouse leave event (when the animating flag is set) to make sure the animation forward has completed before reversing it.

It's a crude solution, but it should be enough to get you going.

### Edit:

The above code reverses the animation, but does not continue it - here's what you need to continue in the same direction. Note: it's a little hacky and has only been tested in Chrome.

### JavaScript

```
$(".cube").bind('transitionend', function() {

    // Reversing the animation flag for the mouse-leave
    if ($(this).data("animating")) {
        $(this).data("animating", false);
    } else {
        $(this).data("animating", true);
    }
});

$('.cube').mouseenter(function(event){
    $(this).data('animating', true);
    $(this).toggleClass('show-back',true);
});

$('.cube').mouseleave(function(event){
    $that = $(this);
    if ($that.data("animating")) {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            $that.toggleClass('show-back',false);
            $that.toggleClass('show-back-again',true);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $that.toggleClass('show-back-again',false);
            }, 50);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $that.toggleClass('show-back',false);
        $that.toggleClass('show-back-again',true);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $that.toggleClass('show-back-again',false);
        }, 50);
    }
});
```

### CSS

```
#cube.show-back-again {
-webkit-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY( -360deg );
 -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY( -360deg );
   -o-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY( -360deg );
      transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY( -360deg );
}
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hSnS/3/)

Comment: Just tested Firefox, doesn't seem to work quite as well.  Oh well :) It was fun.

Comment: I see what you're doing there! I'll see if I can exploit the animating item by adding some timestamp to ensure a smooth transition.

But I'm afraid I'll have to settle with some pausing since you'll have to move past a certain point every time... It will be the same problem as I expect using keyframes :S

Comment: I fiddled a little more: this is the result! http://jsfiddle.net/aldejager/vgPcK/5/

Comment: Neat - but it looks like Firefox has taken a hit with the latest changes.

Comment: My bet, I didn't update the css for all browsers. Should be better now?